# wso2 mss 1.0 alpha there is no clear port defined

Tags: wso2, wso2-msf4j, msf4j

I am trying to have a test on wso2 mss 1.0. After following sample of https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSS100/Running+a+Basic+Microservice, the url curl localhost:8080/hello/Microservices cannot be accessed. 
Also there is no port configured in wso2mss-1.0.0-alpha\repository\conf\carbon.xml.

Comment: Updated link should be https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSF4J100/Running+a+Basic+Microservice

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can configured the port using conf/transports/netty-transports.yml. By default port is set to 8080.